# Multi Level Grouping of ListView In Xamarin.Forms for iOS and Android

Tags: c#, android, ios, listview, xamarin.forms

I'm building an app in Xamarin.Forms. 
I've implemented a list view (SfListView) with grouping and multiple group levels.

***Question 1:*** I want the TermCode grouping to be sticky and the others not to be sticky.

***Question 2:*** I want to have different templates for each grouping i.e. I need say, an image in the course names grouping but not in the term code grouping

The code below is how I'm creating my list view. For background info: CourseName returns a string with the name of the course, TermCode is something like 1234 and TermName is a string with the name for the term:-

```
        listView.ItemSize = 100;

        listView.ItemsSource = Globals.Dataset;
        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
            var grid = new Grid();

            var stack = new StackLayout() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand };
            SfCircularProgressBar circularProgressBar = new SfCircularProgressBar();
            circularProgressBar.SetBinding(ProgressBarBase.ProgressProperty, new Binding("OverallPercent"));
            stack.Children.Add(circularProgressBar);

            grid.Children.Add(stack);
            return grid;
        });

        listView.DataSource.GroupDescriptors.Add(new GroupDescriptor()
        {
            PropertyName = "TermCode",
            KeySelector = (object obj) =>
            {
                return (obj as Data).TermName;
            }

        });
        listView.DataSource.GroupDescriptors.Add(new GroupDescriptor()
        {
            PropertyName = "CourseName",
            KeySelector = (object obj) =>
            {
                return (obj as Data).CourseName;
            }

        });

        listView.GroupHeaderTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            var grid = new Grid();
            Binding binding = new Binding("Level");
            binding.Converter = new GroupHeaderConverter();
            grid.SetBinding(BackgroundColorProperty, binding);
            grid.SetBinding(Xamarin.Forms.Layout.PaddingProperty, binding);

            var label = new Label() { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };
            label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Key"));
            grid.Children.Add(label);
            return grid;
        });
```

Thanks for the help guys. Any comments or answers are appreciated.

Comment: Hi , about first question , not too much understanding it . About second question , you can custom `ContentView` to implement it with different group view UI (`<DataTemplate><local:CustomContentView>...</local:CustomContentView></DataTemplate>`).

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. For the first question what I meant was this: I have two groups created in my list and I want the outer group's header to be sticky and the inner group's header to not be sticky. As in the outer groups header should remain at the top when i scroll but not the inner groups header. For the second question, I want the two groups to have different data templates, I can't find any document which shows multi level grouping in a list view with different templates for outer and inner groups.

Comment: Okey , maybe an image can explain what needs clearly , this will be helpful . Back to question, if good idea will update here .